# How to promote three different products to three different audiences in one banner?

Tags: conceptualization, advertising

My client requests something like the title described. I do not agree the initial idea though. As they insist on doing in this way, I had to come here to ask for some help.

Let's put the question like this: how would you approach designing an outdoor banner that advertises (for example) suits, work uniforms, and children's clothes?

Normally design starts with the question: "what is the purpose to show to audience?" - but here, there are three very different audiences. How can I go about coming up with ideas that do three very different things?

Comment: Show us what you have attempted so far

Comment: @SaturnsEye，show 3 product pictures, short title for each.  A QR code to scan the app. slogan. etc. I feel it looks not engaging. plz help me to better it. (and it is a outdoor banner)

Comment: @SaturnsEye, i will ask the permission to show the real one. (its not about clothes you know)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're not alone in this problem - supermarkets and department stores also often need to advertise different products to different audiences in the same space.

AFAIK, there are two basic approaches. Choose the first if your brand identity suits all three products, and the second if each product requires a different personality and tone.

- **One brand, presenting the products very simply**. Very clean, with a crisp clear layout and/or lots of whitespace, and very simple clear photographs or strong simple styling that **lets the products do the talking** and lets the audience notice the products that are relevant to them. If there are any USPs like price, add them but focus on clean clarity above all else.

Here's an example ([source](http://www.behance.net/gallery/Asda/925249)). I couldn't find any "lots of whitespace, just photos" examples but I'm sure you can imagine them. In this one, the brand personality is the same, but each product neatly stands out to people interested in that type of product:

[image]

- **'Mini-brands'**. The banner could be divided to look like three banners side by side. This is a good idea if your approach to selling the products is very different. For example, some supermarkets here in the UK have their own clothing brands with different logos and a different brand identity to the supermarket overall - usually this is because they want the supermarket brand to look cheap and friendly, but for clothing, "cheap and cheerful" would look undesirable and unfashionable. So, they **section them off as if they were completely different identities** that just happen to share buildings and ad space.

I can't find any billboard examples (turns out people don't love photographing supermarket billboard ads...) but here's an example of different characters. Asda (left) markets itself as cheap and friendly, but its clothing brand George (right), which is wholly owned by Asda and is only sold in Asda supermarkets, has a very different brand personality:

[image]  [image]

Answer (score 11):

I happen to have one particular image you may find useful. I didn't create this just happen to have found it and thought it was worth adding to my scrapbook of ideas. Its simple, eloquent, and even humorous while showing 3 distinct products that are, at least in theory, for 3 distinct demographics.

[image: Allen Edmund's Ad]

Comment: +1 for such a great example! I was going to try to answer the OP by suggesting filtering down to one shared theme, but your example sums it up better than my words ever could.

Comment: _Why would a doctor need such a shoe? O_o_

Comment: @Lohoris I think there's a running joke in the US that (senior?) doctors spend all their time playing golf. I've seen it in comics etc. I guess it's something to do with them being well paid and managing their own appointments schedule (i.e. they can work when they want)?

Answer (score 2):

I'm picturing a still montage of the progression through life of the same person: first: child in elementary school, second: construction worker, third: executive (the latter two of whom could be the same model), all of whom are donning the splendors of your clothier, whose brand name is somewhat shamelessly stamped under each of the three characters.

The impression: We've got you covered throughout your career path, we facilitate your career path, we make buying clothes for your family easy (playing off the ambiguity of the child's identity in the montage -- is it the same man as a youth, or the man's child as he progresses through his successful career? -- also, the cycle continues through the child's life to his professional career and family life).

Tying together separate ideas into a story, however contrived, still allows an individual only interested in one genre to focus on that, and also to unconsciously incorporate the rest into imagination.

Answer (score 1):

white background + photomanipulation where one person will wear all this three types of clothing + big colored headers with graph lines to that person